# how to add a horizontal scroll bar in column if the text overflows or else it'll be hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I want a add a horizontal scroll bar to a column if the text of the column overflows. I don't want to increase the column width. I've used nowrap text but also want to add horizontal scroll bar to it. And if the text do not overflow then the scroll bar will be hidden. This is my code. Right now this scroll bar is working for the whole column not for any specific column. I've to use JS for this condition but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

***HTML:***

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>Name of the Project</th>
       <th>Name of the Clients</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
   <tr class="active">                                                                             
    <td>1</td>

    <td>Column content</td>

    <td class="tHor">

      Name 1 Name 2

      Name 1 Name 2

      Name 1 Name 2

      Name 1 Name 2

    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

   <td>3</td>

   <td>Column content</td>

   <td class="tHor"> Name 1 Name 2</td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

***CSS:***

```
.tHor{
   overflow-x: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I want this 'tHor' class to have a scrollbar if the text increases in this code, 1st row's column will show the bar but for 2nd row, column the horizontal scroll bar must be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need JavaScript to achieve that. Just set `max-width` property:

```css
.tHor{
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>Name of the Project</th>
      <th>Name of the Clients</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
    <tr class="active">                                                             
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td class="tHor">
        Name 1 Name 2
        Name 1 Name 2
        Name 1 Name 2
        Name 1 Name 2
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td class="tHor"> Name 1 Name 2</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```